# Getting the Logon_User in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication

I have a .NET 4 application that I am taking to IIS 7.5.  In it, I have the following code:
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]
This code is in my global.asax file and is in my Application_BeginRequest method.

For my application, this is returning an empty string.  That makes me think that I don't have my authentication setup.  I go into the IIS admin manager, and I have Anonymous, Digest, and Forms Authentication disabled.  I have ASP.NET Impersonation, Basic, and Windows Authentication enabled.

Any ideas regarding what I need to do to get the actual windows auth userid would be appreciated.

Wally

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx (somewhere in the middle)
It explains which events are executed when a request comes in. BeginRequest is one of the first events that are raised when a request comes in and this means that not every piece of information you might need is available yet. In your case try capturing the  `PostAuthenticateRequest` and see if that works. Also, you might be interested in `User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: Thanks ZippyV.  It seems to be working properly.  Now I have other issues to work through.